# How to make a tooltip without needing any child elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, tooltip

I've been trying to make a tooltip that activates upon hovering an `<a>` tag and displays a `<div>` from another place

Example:

```
<p>
blah blah <a class="tooltiphover">hover me</a> blah blah
</p>

<div class="tooltip">
<!-- tooltip info code goes here -->
</div>
```

But every tutorial and site I've stumbled upon has been adamant on using child elements and biggest problem with that is it makes the code look bad or forces me to use a `<div>` tag which then screws up the look of the site

Example:

```
<div class="tooltiphover">Hover me</div>
    <span class="tooltip">Tooltip stuff</span>
</div>
```

Especially when it comes to their css with `.tooltiphover:hover .tooltip`.

Also if there is any way to call for both elements in css to be modified when one is hovered, without being a child element, that would be great as well because adding a comma doesn't seem to do the trick and neither does adding a plus

Thanks.

EDIT: Actually, to make it simpler, how would I make the div appear in front of everything and appear next to the `<a>` tag like a proper tooltip because I might just use JS to deal with the `mouseover` event. To be honest, not sure why I went through the effort of trying to use CSS and HTML for this when it is a lot easier with JS, but I think it was probably due to all the tooltip tutorials I searched up confused me too much

What would be the CSS code for that?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this, and note that none specifically require a `<div>` tag. CSS has many different types of [selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) with different rules for how each behave. Generally speaking, CSS cascades and interacts *forwards*, meaning it can be difficult to interact with elements prior in your document (i.e. a child telling its parent how to behave is rare.)

The most common type of selector for this is either the `element element` selector or the `element > element` selector. They require the affected/target element be a child of the parent element.

They look something like this.

```css
div:hover > h2{
  display:block;
}

h2{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div>hover me
<h2>i am revealed</h2>
</div>

<p>don't hover me</p>
```

However, as you said, this requires a highly coupled relationship between the element you are selecting for and its parent. This is where the `element ~ element` selector comes into play.

```css
div:hover ~ h2{
  display:block;
}

h2{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div>hover me</div>

<p>don't hover me</p>

<h2>i am revealed</h2>
```

Where `element > element` requires a vertical relationship between your *parent and child*, `element ~ element` requires a horizontal *sibling* relationship. In the example given, all elements matching your selection would be revealed so long as they are siblings within the same context.

But what would happen if your desired target was a child of a sibling, rather than the sibling itself?

```css
div:hover ~ h2{
  display:block;
}

h2{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div>hover me</div>

<p>don't hover me</p>

<article>
  <h2>i am revealed</h2>
</article>
```

Oh no! It doesn't work now, because they are no longer siblings within the same context. There are many ways to solve this issue, both general and specific, but one simple way is as follows:

```css
div:hover ~ * h2{
  display:block;
}

h2{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div>hover me</div>

<p>don't hover me</p>

<article>
  <h2>i am revealed</h2>
<article>
```

By combining the `element ~ element` selector with the `* element` selector, we can interact with any h2 that is a child of any sibling of our original selector with the *:hover* pseudo-class.

If I am understanding the second part of your question correctly, and you want both the hover element AND its target to change in some way when the hover event takes place, it's as simple as separately declaring the styles.

```css
div:hover ~ * h2{
  display:block;
}

div:hover{
  color: red;
}

h2{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div>hover me and i turn red</div>

<p>don't hover me</p>

<article>
  <h2>i am revealed and not red</h2>
<article>
```

Comment: This is almost exactly how I wanted it, but it is still using a `<div>` instead of an anchor inside of a paragraph to display a `<div>`, but this has given me somewhat of a starting point, so I will continue messing around with the code, thank you

Comment: Note that there is nothing special about the `div` element. While it has some pre-determined behavior (display: block), it is as good as any other container as far as selectors go. In any of my examples, you can replace every instance of `div` with `p` and the :hover selector will work identically. https://jsfiddle.net/on196Lve/


The problem comes when you want to select "upwardly", i.e, your example of an `anchor` inside a `p`. In terms of pure CSS, this can only be accomplished with some kind of vertical relationship, because CSS only cascades and interacts forwards.

Comment: So, instead, I recommend either changing your code such that the anchor tag behaves like the paragraph you want, or by setting your `:hover` event to the `p` itself.

https://jsfiddle.net/doz0w4eg/1/

Comment: Ended up reverting back to JS and attempting to style the div to look and appear like a proper tooltip. Regardless, thanks for all your help. Much appreciated!